# open limitation based on file size

Tags: linux, file, filesystems, linux-kernel

Is there any limitation on "open" based on file size. ?
My file size is 2 GB will it open successfully and is there any timing issue can come ?
filesystem is rootfs.

Comment: What business do you have creating a 2GB file in *rootfs*? http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt

Comment: Its keep on getting bigger due to some error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `open` man page:

> `O_LARGEFILE`
>
> (LFS)  Allow files whose sizes cannot be represented in an `off_t`
>   (but can be represented  in  an  `off64_t`)  to  be  opened.   The
>   `_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE`  macro  must  be  defined in order to obtain
>   this definition.  Setting  the  `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS`  feature  test
>   macro  to  64  (rather  than using `O_LARGEFILE`) is the preferred
>   method of obtaining method of accessing large  files  on  32-bit
>   systems (see `feature_test_macros`(7)).

On a 64-bit system, `off_t` will be 64 bits and you'll have no problem. On a 32-bit system, you'll need the suggested workaround to allow for files larger than 2 GB.

Answer (score 2):

rootfs may not support large files; consider using a proper filesystem instead (tmpfs is almost the same as rootfs, but with more features).

rootfs is intended only for booting and early use.